# How do I add a custom file to the Composer to ignore when upgrading?

Tags: smarty, composer-php

I have installed smarty via the Composer, like below,

```
"require": 
  {
    "neitanod/forceutf8": "dev-master",
    "raven/raven": "0.7.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.7.*",
    "smarty/smarty": "3.1.19"
  }
```

However I have custom plugin that needs to be added to the smarty/plugin lib to be used with the website. So when I update composer to the upgrade the smarty it gives me an error. How do I add my custom plugin to the smarty via composer so that I dont have redo this again and again, ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't keep your plugin anywhere in smarty's vendor directory. Put it somewhere sensible along with the rest of your application and use [`$smarty->addPluginsDir('path/to/your/custom/plugin/dir')`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.add.plugins.dir.tpl) instead.

Comment: thanks, if i move the plugin directory somewhere else do i have copy all the other default pligins too in there ?

Comment: yes, that solved the problem with smarty, however i have same problem with symfony too, where i wrote some custom date functions.. how do i solve that problem,